# Pandas Dataframe Display Precision by row

Tags: python, pandas, latex, precision

I am using pandas to output my results to LaTeX. I currently set my precision (number of decimals to print out) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1234.56, 0.01, 1234.56],'b':[1234.56, 0.01, 1234.56]})

pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)

df.to_latex('filename.tex')
```

This works really well. But I would like the precision to be different for specific rows of my dataframe (and resulting TeX table). Is it possible to do this with pandas?

For this example, I want rows 0 and 2 to print with no decimal places and row 1 to print with 2 decimal places, as follows:

```
 df
      a     b
 0    1234  1234
 1    0.01  0.01
 2    1234  1234
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  However, your question is too vague.  I could give an example but I don't want to take the time to give an example just to have you tell me that it isn't exactly what you were looking for.  Why would I ever think that might happen... probably because its happened too many times already.  You should provide a good example of what you are trying to do.  Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to give you a better idea on how to present your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I hope my example is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a crappy answer and I'm too tired to think of a better one.  But I didn't want to leave you hanging after I half lectured you on question quality.

```
p = pd.Series([1, 2, 0], df.index)

df.apply(lambda x: x.map(p.map(lambda x: '{{:0.{}f}}'.format(x).format).loc[x.name]), 1)

        a       b
0  1234.6  1234.6
1    0.01    0.01
2    1235    1235
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!